# Chrome extension - check if domain has been visited in past 24 hours?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to setup a background script in a Chrome extension.

All I'm wanting to do is monitor URLs that are visited and check to see if the domain has been visited in the past 24 hours (from their history).  It doesn't matter if they've visited the specific URL they're on - just the domain or subdomain.

From what I've studied, it looks like I can use this to monitor the URLs being visited:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener((details) => {
    if (details.type == "main_frame") {
        checkDomain(details.url);
    }
}, {
    urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
});

function checkDomain(url) {
    try {
        let pattern = /(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]/g;
        let domain = url.match(pattern);
        if (domain && domain.length) {
            /// Log to console if domain has NOT been visited in the past 24 hours...
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

I guess what I'm not sure about is how to put it all together and check the past 24 hours of history.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [chrome.history API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history).

Comment: Also, 1) use `types: ['main_frame']` in the [filter parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36208398) instead of intercepting everything, 2) consider using `new URL(url).hostname` instead of regexp.