# How to auto reload page with chrome extension when http 500 error was return by server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-headers, http-status-code-500

Because it isn't possible to use Greasemonkey/tampermonkey for this, I want to write a Chrome extension that will reload a page if it initially failed to load due to server error.

i want to create an extension that will keep reloading every opening tabs if the page keep returning http 500 error.

i'm not that good writing Chrome extension,but I've done some reading on https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index and was able to code up an extension to check the http header returned by the server using https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest onHeadersReceived event to check the return status and reload it if the return status was 500.

**Probem**
It works but its only reloading only the current tap not on all the other openings tabs running in background.

**Reason why i need this extension**
i'm opening all links from a websites at once using a grease monkey script i coded  and i want if the link page opening was  unable to open due to http 500 error, i want the extension to keep reloading it and wanted it to work for all the other tabs running the opening links in the background

***MY CODE SO FAR***

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "name": "RWEO",
  "version": "0.4",
  "description": "Reload page when Http 500 error occur",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webNavigation",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": true
  }
 
}
```

*background.js*

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function(details) {

        if (details.statusCode == 500) {
            var repeat = 0 
            var check = setInterval(() => {
                chrome.tabs.reload({ bypassCache: false })
                if (repeat == 3) {
                    clearInterval(check)
                } , 5000})
         repeat++
        }


    }, { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }, );
```

Comment: I think the problem might be with Chrome trying to save computer resources, and therefore only handling active tabs. It's seen when opening a lot of tabs and not using some of them for a while.

Comment: One mistake I see: you need to specify tab id in reload: chrome.tabs.reload(details.tabId, { bypassCache: false }) and another possible mistake is that you probably need to limit the types to `main_frame`, [random example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36208398).

Comment: @wOxxOm it works now by adding the tabId, its actually want i should have tried but i thought its not the problem while it was it  and how can i limit the types to main_frame ?

Comment: See the example I've linked.

Comment: I want this as well. Did you end up getting something working that you can share or link to, @Harfho?

Comment: Alternatively, for others looking for a Chrome extension that has at least the base functionality of continually retrying a page that failed to load, the [Error Page Enhanced](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/error-page-enhanced/phnaagakdgflhjpekoiklejdgadnlbgc/) Chrome extension has this as part of its primary functionality.

Comment: @Andrew D. Bond , Yes i do. I was able to build a perfectly working chrome extension for it. Though i didn't share it to the Public. U need it? Text me on twitter(harfho)